# React native: how to combine index.ios.js and index.android.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using a panel module [Expanding/Collapsing a panel with animations in React Native](https://github.com/crysfel/Panels)

This library contains two .js files

**index.ios.js:**

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

import React,{AppRegistry,StyleSheet,Text,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import Panel from './components/Panel';

var Panels = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Panel title="A Panel with short content text">
          <Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</Text>
        </Panel>
        <Panel title="A Panel with long content text">
          <Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</Text>
        </Panel>
        <Panel title="Another Panel">
          <Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.</Text>
        </Panel>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex            : 1,
    backgroundColor : '#f4f7f9',
    paddingTop      : 30
  },

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Panels', () => Panels);
```

**index.android.js**

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;
var Panels = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Panels', () => Panels);
```

I want to combine these two files in the one `index.js` Is there a way I could do this? I want this library to work on both ios and android devices. 
Any advice or comments would be appreciated thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The one of simple ways is to use `index.js` only. You can separate some codes in `index.js` through [Platform](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code)

## Why?

#### Priority of index

index.ios.js = index.android.js > index.js

Answer (score 0):

I guess `index.ios.js` is the file you want with android also right? It is working with `ios` and now you want it to be work fine in `android` also.

It's simple, follow these steps and you are done.

1. Delete `index.android.js`
2. Rename `index.ios.js` to `index.js`